# mySQL multiple Join with empty result line

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, exists

I have two tables `CLIENSTS` and `PRICES` and I wanto to join them in order to calculate total prices amount per item type, ***every year***. 
My query has to sum every item's value, grouping them by type, and than times them with the corresponding item's type amount in clients table; showing also and empty value if there are no items for the selected year.

Here my tables:

```
CLIENTS
| name | item_A | item_B | item_C |
|  X   |   10   |   10   |   10   |
|  Y   |    5   |   15   |    0   |
|  Z   |    0   |    0   |   20   |

PRICES
| item | item_type | year | value |
|  a1  |     A     | 2010 |   1   |
|  a2  |     A     | 2010 |   2   |
|  b1  |     B     | 2010 |   2   | 
|  b2  |     B     | 2010 |   3   |
|  c1  |     C     | 2010 |   3   |
|  a1  |     A     | 2011 |   4   |
|  b1  |     B     | 2011 |   5   |
```

I'm looking for a query able to perform the sequent results for every year selected:

```
2010
| name | price_A | price_B | price_C |
|  X   |    30   |    60   |    30   |
|  Y   |    15   |    90   |     0   |
|  Z   |     0   |     0   |    60   |

2011
| name | price_A | price_B | price_C        |
|  X   |    40   |    50   | none/null/zero |
|  Y   |    20   |    75   | none/null/zero |
|  Z   |     0   |     0   | none/null/zero |
```

This is my attempt, but unfortunately it performs correctly for the first year (2010) and returns no line for the second (2011).
I suppose it is due to the third join which has not `total_C` resutls on second year.
Which is the correct way to ask mySQL to join the tabe "*if the result exists*" or place the value as "*none/null/zero*" ?

```
SELECT 
`name`, 
`item_A` * `total_A`.`total_value` AS  `price_A`,
`item_B` * `total_B`.`total_value` AS  `price_B`, 
`item_C` * `total_C`.`total_value` AS  `price_C`
FROM `CLIENTS`
JOIN
 (
SELECT 
`item_type`,
SUM(`value`) AS `total_value`
FROM `PRICES` 
WHERE `item_type`='A' AND `year` LIKE '2010'
GROUP BY `item_type`
) AS `total_A`
JOIN
 (
SELECT 
`item_type`,
SUM(`value`) AS `total_value`
FROM `PRICES` 
WHERE `item_type`='B' AND `year` LIKE '2010'
GROUP BY `item_type`
) AS `total_B`
JOIN
 (
SELECT 
`item_type`,
SUM(`value`) AS `total_value`
FROM `PRICES` 
WHERE `item_type`='C' AND `year` LIKE '2010'
GROUP BY `item_type`
) AS `total_C`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you should use something like this:

```
SELECT
  s.year,
  clients.name,
  clients.item_A*s.sum_A,
  clients.item_B*s.sum_B,
  clients.item_C*s.sum_C
FROM
  clients INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    year,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_type='A' THEN value END) sum_A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_type='B' THEN value END) sum_B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_type='C' THEN value END) sum_C
  FROM
    prices
  GROUP BY
    year) s
ORDER BY
  s.year
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca5ae/1).

On the subquery I'm summing the total values, for item_type, for every year. Then I'm doing a cartesian join with the clients table.

Comment: Yes! thank you. It is a different approach, your joined subquery generates a bigger table with not null values on its main diagonal but all the query is faster and smaller than mine... ad works!